# Canvas - Circle pie shape for preloader

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

What I'm trying to get done in the example shown below is a pie like shape for a preloader script. The deal with it is that it starts on 0% and finishes on 100%. Depending on the % given the circle behind the gray circle shall fill it self up.

Currently i have the shapes in 2 different canvas's as i had to use clip to actually hide parts of the circle. But as this applied to my overlay with the gray circle i spliced them up. They are by the way both images.

[image: Preloader]

I would really appreciate any effort that you guys put in helping me.
Been trying to solve this issue for ages.

Comment: Can you please post code for how you managed to clip the black image? or some reference link? i am stuck there.please help.

Comment: Used the .save() and .restore() methods built in. An example can be seen here: http://mvc-loader.com/dlb/index_1_loader.htm - Code: http://mvc-loader.com/dlb/js/jquery.dlb.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
Seems like i had to use the moveTo
function in order to get the shape to be painted correctly.

Using the

```
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
}
```

function to use degrees rather than Radians.

-

Hope this helps someone else :)